# persist tomcat jndi settings

Tags: tomcat, jndi

We would like to pass the same WAR thru dev, test, and production. How can we persist our JNDI settings w/o manual modification of server.xml? For example, in Websphere there is an admin console, and the JNDI resources can be added manually and saved, or using jacl/jython script out the addition of the necesary JNDI resources.

Why does tomcat "recommend" to use context.xml? This means we need a separate build for each environment... this is not really JNDI then...it's a glorified JNDI xml property file, since context.xml needs to be bundled in the WAR, and whenever we redeploy (undeploy, deploy, start app) we lose the existing context.xml

Answer (score 1):

So your actual problem is that you want some webinterface provided by Tomcat to manage the JNDI resources without manually editing the `server.xml` (which WAS actually also does "under the hood").

Tomcat doesn't ship by default with an admin webinterface like that, only the manager which you already know. I know there are admin tools for Tomcat 5.5.x, you can find it [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/tomcat-5/v5.5.12/bin/), unfortunately there's no such tool for Tomcat 6.x. I haven't tried it but you may try to see if it works with Tomcat 6.x as well.

Comment: Yea...tried it admin with Tomcat6, though it had errors when saving configuration, mbean storeconfig is no longer available...